# Configure Selenium - Capybara on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, capybara, configure

I'm using Chrome as my default user while testing with Capybara. What I want to do is configure that chrome instance so that it doesn't suggest remembering username and password on a login page.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should customize [Chrome's profile](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Chrome):

Try to set `extensions.password_manager_enabled` to false:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile['extensions.password_manager_enabled'] = false
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, profile: profile)
end
```

If it doesn't work, look at other Chrome preferences and switches.

Comment: I got this error "NameError: uninitialized constant Selenium" do I have to include any specific file ?

Comment: @AlperMermer You should `require 'selenium-webdriver'`

Comment: profile['extensions.password_manager_enabled'] = false doesn't work. Found this code but it didn't work either
profile['autologin.enabled'] = false